# Getting href with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get the href with selenium and python.

This is my page:

[image]

Some class information are changing depending on which elements. So I am trying basically to get all href for `<a id="job____ .....`

```
links.append(job.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@aria-live="polite"]//span').get_attribute(name="href"))
```

I tried couple of things but can't figure out how. How can i get all my href from the screenshot above?

Comment: This looks OK to me. Are you sure your xpath is correct? Have you tried this on other anchor tags?

Comment: It's not compleetly clear what you want. 
Do you want to get the href on that spesiffic id or on all <a>s on the page?

Comment: Hi @DimitarVeljanovski NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@aria-live="polite"]//span"}

Comment: @BendikKnapstad I want to get the href from all the <a Id = "job_....> which have a href

Comment: @SimonGIS seems to me like the issue is with finding the element and not obtaining an href attribute. You are essentially trying to obtain the href of an element that doesnt exist. Try getting the anchor through its CSS selector or its ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, but take care your xpath

"//a[@aria-live="polite"]//span"

will get a span, and i dont see any span with href on your html. Maybe this xpath solve it

//a[./span[@aria-live="polite"]]

```
links.append(job.find_element_by_xpath('//a[./span[@aria-live="polite"]]').get_attribute("href"))
```

But it wont get all urls, this with find_elements (return a list), extend your url list with list comprehension

```
links.extend([x.get_attribute("href") for x in job.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[./span[@aria-live="polite"]]')])
```

edit 1, other xpath solution

```
links.extend(["website_base_url"+x.get_attribute("href") for x in job.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@id, "job_")]')])
```

Comment: with the second solution i am getting this error: links.extend([x.get_attribute("href") for x in job.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[./span[@aria-live="polite"]]')])

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Ok, i will edit with other xpath and you let me know if works. I edited it, added too the option to concatenate base_url to get a good link

Comment: cant make it work out. May I share you my code on chat?

Comment: Sure, open it and we will check it

Answer (score 1):

```
list_of_elements_with_href = wd.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'')]")
for el_with_href in list_of_elements_with_href :
 links.append(el.with_href.get_attribute("href"))
```

or if you need more specify:

```
list_of_elements_with_href = wd.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'') and contains(@id,'job_')]")
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description and attached image, I think you have got the wrong xpath. Try the following code.

```
find_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[starts-with(@id,'job_')]")

links = []
for link in find_links:
        links.append(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

Please note `elements` in `find_elements_by_xpath` instead of `element`.

I am unable to test this solution as you have not provided the website.